# DateTime.Parse throws an exception with Optimse Code compiler option

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7.5

In my project I have the line

```
DateTime alarmDateTime = DateTime.Parse(AlarmTimeStamp.Text);
```

AlarmTimeStamp.Text is for example `"04/09/2015 10:23"` (The computer's Region setting is English UK)

This throws a FormatException, but only when the Optimise Code compiler setting is on, i.e. a Release build. If I turn this off, it works as expected.

I'm not sure where to begin with debugging this since the debugger doesn't work correctly with optimised code.

If it's relevant, this is from a ASP.Net Web Forms application, .Net 3.5 hosted in Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5.

Edit:
I have done some testing and found that this only occurs on one of my servers. I have 2 servers configured, a development and test. This issue only occurring on my development server. There is no difference between them though. They are both built from the same image.

Comment: Does this work: `DateTime alarmDateTime = DateTime.Parse("04/09/2015 10:23", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));`?

Comment: No this still crashes in a release build.

Comment: Is the relase build overwritten at all, so does it use the code that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this..

```
    string timeString = AlarmTimeStamp.Text;
    IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
    DateTime alarmDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", culture);
```

Comment: Why `en-US` if OP uses `en-GB` and that works also without `ParseExact`? `DateTime alarmDateTime = DateTime.Parse("04/09/2015 10:23", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));`